# Magento2: How to use custom font

Tags: magento2, fonts, font-family

I have download and upload custom font in backend:
[image]

After save in editor I not see this font name:
[image]

Anyone help how can I use this font ?

@update

I solve issue in this way. After upload font:

```
<style xml="space"><!--
@font-face {
font-family: 'DIN Pro Condensed Regular';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('DIN Pro Condensed Regular'), url('DINPro-Cond.woff') format('woff');
}
p.dinpro {
  font-family: DIN Pro Condensed Regular;
}
--></style>
<p class="dinpro">Text with your font</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can import your new font like this:

1. > style.css

   ```
   @font-face {
       font-family: Dinpro;
       src: url(../fonts/Dinpro.ttf);
   }
   ```
2. You put your `Dinpro.ttf` in `app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{themename}/web/fonts/Dinpro.ttf`
3. You deploy the static-content
4. You use the new font like this

   > style.css

   ```
   .product-name {
       font-family: Dinpro;
   }
   ```